# I want to make img element a parent element for paragraph element

Tags: javascript, dom

How do I insert paragraph element in img element as parent element.

```
<img src="rest.jpg" class="imgone" alt=""></li>
let para=document.createElement("p");
let paraText=document.createTextNode("Description");
para.appendChild(paraText);
para.style.widht="300px";
para.style.height="400px";
para.style.position="absolute";
para.style.border="2px";
para.style.borderColor="black";
let img=document.querySelector(".imgone");
img.nextElementSibling=dest.textContent;
```

Answer (score 1):

`<img>` elements are "empty elements" and thus cannot have child elements inside of them (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#Technical_summary)).

If you want to overlay a paragraph over an image, give them a shared parent (perhaps a `<div>`) and use CSS to position the paragraph over the image (`position:absolute` and co.).

```js
let paraText=document.createTextNode("Description");
let para=document.createElement("p");
para.appendChild(paraText);
para.style.widht="300px";
para.style.height="400px";
para.style.position="absolute";

// paragraphs come with margin by default, do you want it?
para.style.margin = "0";

// position is required for element to actually move somewhere
para.style.left = "2px";
para.style.top = "2px";

// you were missing a border style (solid/etc.)
para.style.border="2px solid black";

let img=document.querySelector(".imgone");

// add the paragraph after the element
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentElement
img.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', para);

// required for text to align relative to element
// https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position
img.parentElement.style.position = "relative";
```

```html
<ul>
<li><img src="https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-l_1zd0-u7V8/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAK4/pt6IIe-G62s/photo.jpg?sz=48" class="imgone" alt=""></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I gave them <li> what next please.

Comment: Here you go, added an example to the answer